# Snapshotting a Python process and restoring from it at a later point

Tags: python

Let's say I run a Python program, and it gets to a particular point in the execution of it. I want to be able to take a "snapshot" of this state to be able to run it at a future point.

eg:

- I run test1.py which goes about creating objects, sessions, etc. and hits breakpoint-1.
- I take a "snapshot" of the Python process and then continue the program.
- At a later stage, I want to be able to restore from the "snapshot" and execute the program starting at breakpoint-1.

Why do I want this? To execute a particular task repeatedly, if the start is pretty mundane and only the end is interesting, then I don't want to waste time in running the first part every time.

Any suggestions, or pointers to how I can do this, or what tools I should be looking at?

Comment: Or some sort of persistent data store like `pickle` to hold intermediary values?

Comment: I would suggest passing in a command-line argument to tell it whether or not to skip the initial stuff. Unless you really really really need a general solution, then look into pickle

Comment: I assume "At a later stage" means after the program has finished? (if not, use a function)

Comment: I like @g.d.d.c's suggestion. Hold all of the state you want to save in a base object and pickle it. Not all objects are picklable, but its worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need something that does persistent memoization.  This is rudimentary, but might get you started:

```
import shelve

class MemoizedProcessor(object):
  def __init__(self):
    # writeback only if it can't be assured that you'll close this shelf.
    self.preprocessed = shelve.open('preprocessed.cache', writeback = True)
    if 'inputargs' not in self.preprocessed:
      self.preprocessed['inputargs'] = dict()

  def __del__(self, *args):
    self.preprocessed.close()

  def process(self, *args):
    if args not in self.preprocessed['inputargs']:
      self._process(*args)
    return self.preprocessed['inputargs'][args]

  def _process(self, *args):
    # Something that actually does heavy work here.
    result = args[0] ** args[0]
    self.preprocessed['inputargs'][args] = result
```